# Tool for comparing Xcode project files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, version-control

I've been given the Xcode project files for version 1 and 2 of a iOS app. Version 1 is working, version 2 is buggy with more features. The original programmer is no longer available. No versioning system was used.

Is there a tool to compare the different projects - so I can see what code was added between version 1 & 2?

Comment: use a versioning tool, make one project the initial commit and than overwrite it with the other project so you will see the differences

Comment: i used github for mac.. it's a bit flakey but it does the job

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that nearly everything in an xcode project is stored in text files so you should be able to use standard [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) tools to compare the projects. This, of course, excludes resources such as images, audio, etc.

[FileMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#FileMerge) is an app that comes with Apple's Developer tools. It does diffs and merges. It can be run through the terminal with the the [`opendiff`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/opendiff/) command.

Answer (score 27):

You can compare two Xcode project using FileMerge tool available with Xcode.

Below are steps for comparison in Xcode 6.1

1. Right click on **Xcode icon** -> Select '**Open Developer Tool'** -> Select **'FileMerge'** option

[image: Screenshot 0]

2. This will open window as show below :

[image: Screenshot 1]

3. Select two Xcode project which is to be compared by clicking **Left and Right button**
4. Click on **'Compare'** button. This will create list of file that are added, removed or altered
   by comparing two Xcode project.

[image: Screenshot 2]